# Using sed to get IPv4 adresses of file and export with prefix

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file **iplist.txt** with contents:

```
1.2.3.4
127.0.0.1
192.168.1.0/24
1111:2222:3333:4444::
5.6.7.8
```

im trying to find a way out to export a new file **WITHOUT IPv6** and with prefix on every line something like that:

**exportediplist.txt**

```
/ip add address=1.2.3.4
/ip add address=127.0.0.1
/ip add address=192.168.1.0/24
/ip add address=5.6.7.8
```

the first thing i`ve tryied to do is to add a prefix with:

```
originalfile=/somepath/iplist.txt
exportedfile=/somepath/exportediplist.txt
sed -e 's#^#/ip add address=#' $originalfile > $exportedfile
```

and it works ok but i can`t figure out how to remove IPv6 from file. It`s not important to use sed, just anything that works with debian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU `sed`, you can use

```
sed -En '/([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+/{s,,/ip add address=&,p}' $originalfile > $exportedfile
```

Or, a bit more precise expression to match entire IPv4-like lines:

```
sed -En '/^([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+(\/[0-9]+)?$/{s,,/ip add address=&,p}' $originalfile > $exportedfile
```

See [`sed` online demo #1](https://ideone.com/CyrkBR) and [demo #2](https://ideone.com/YqvIqe).

**Details**

- `-En` - `E` enables POSIX ERE syntax and `n` suppresses default line output
- `/([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+/` - finds all lines with dot-separated 4 numbers
- `/^([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+(\/[0-9]+)?$/` is the same, but additionally checks for start of string (`^`) and end of string (`$`) and also matches an optional port number after `/` with `(\/[0-9]+)?`
- `s,,/ip add address=&,` - on the lines found, replaces the match with `/ip add address=` + match value
- `p` - prints the outcome.

Answer (score 4):

A `grep/sed` combo:

```
$ egrep -v ':' iplist.txt | sed 's|^|/ip add address=|g'
/ip add address=1.2.3.4
/ip add address=127.0.0.1
/ip add address=192.168.1.0/24
/ip add address=5.6.7.8
```

Another idea using just `sed`:

```
$ sed '/:/d;s|^|/ip add address=|g' iplist.txt
/ip add address=1.2.3.4
/ip add address=127.0.0.1
/ip add address=192.168.1.0/24
/ip add address=5.6.7.8
```

Where:

- `/:/d` - skips/deletes any line containing a colon (`:`)
- `s|^|ip add address'|g` - prefaces the remaining lines with the desired string

One `awk` idea:

```
$ awk '/:/ { next } { printf "/ip add address=%s\n", $0}' iplist.txt
/ip add address=1.2.3.4
/ip add address=127.0.0.1
/ip add address=192.168.1.0/24
/ip add address=5.6.7.8
```

Answer (score 3):

A very simple one-liner `awk`:

```sh
 awk '!/:/{print "/ip add address="$0}' infile >outfile
```

How it works:

- `!/:/`: If it contains no colon character, select line for processing.
- `{print "/ip add address="$0}`: Process line by adding the new prefix stuffs.